# Rails efficiently maintain a list of directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a VERY simple PHP site that basically provides a list of folders, with a couple of buttons for each folder. At the moment, as there isn't much to do, it reads the folder contents on every page refresh.  The list itself is not stored anywhere.

Now I'm looking to store more information for each folder (what user has accessed it, when it was etc).  I'm learning Rails and would like to do it in that, so my question:

How to efficiently read the folders in to the Rails DB without having to refresh them every time.

I'm not asking for someone to write it for me, just give me some ideas as to the path I should be looking at.

What I want to avoid is having to scan the folder and compare each directory with the DB to see if it exists or not as this could become pretty expensive as the folder grows.  Or is that really the best way?

Maybe set up a cron job to scan the folders and add them to the DB separate from the web server?

**TL:DR - Need help regarding an efficient way to maintain a folder list in Rails DB.**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the operating system you are using, you could use the modified date or creation date on the directories to determine if you should check the database for existence.  Save the date/time of the last check and only consider directories that have been created or modified since that date/time.

Another option would be to have a daemon running that "watches" the directory tree and any time it changes, updates the database.  This could be as simple as running `ls -l` through a sha-1 hash to get a kind of signature, and any time that signature changes, running the full directory-tree-to-database sync.

For writing daemons in Rails, consider the [daemon-rails](https://github.com/mirasrael/daemons-rails) gem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I will look at generating a hash for the directory and using that. Seems like it would probably be the most efficient way.